# How to print ID value as a custom text value?

Tags: sql, t-sql

How could I change numeric ID value to word just when printing select results?

```
SELECT sku_price, sku_name, sku_group_id
```

and getting:

```
99.99    iPhone    9
```

and finally I want to change sku_group_id (which is "9") to text value, ex "cellphones"

I want to see that text values only when printing select (just for the better view), without any impact to database.

Comment: did u tried to Cast( sku_group_id as varchar(255) )

Comment: Do u have any reference table to say value equals to a ' string' ?

Comment: No, any reference - it would be just my "custom name" of that ID value.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT
    sku_price,
    sku_name,
    CASE WHEN sku_group_id = 9 THEN 'cellphones'
         WHEN sku_group_id = 8 THEN 'laptops'
         ... ELSE 'default' END AS sku_group_label
FROM yourTable;
```

For a better long term solution, you could maintain a table which maps `sku_group_id` values to textual descriptions, and then join to this table, e.g.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 9 AS sku_group_id, 'cellphones' AS sku_group_label UNION ALL
    SELECT 8, 'laptops'
    ...
)

SELECT
    t1.sku_price,
    t1.sku_name,
    COALESCE(t2.sku_group_label, 'default') AS sku_group_label
FROM yourTable t1
LEFT JOIN cte t2
    ON t1.sku_group_id = t2.sku_group_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have a sku_group table as your column is named sku_group_id and using the following sample table structure (making an assumption here)

```
Sku group table 
    +-------------+----------+
    |Sku_Group_ID |GroupName |
    +-------------+----------+
    | 9           |Cellphones|
    | 10          | Tablets  |
    +-------------+----------+
```

Then a simple join could be what you are after

```
Select Sku.Sku_Price,
Sku.Sku_Name,
Group.GroupName
FROM Sku_Table As Sku
Inner JOIN Sku_Group As Group
ON Sku.Sku_Group_ID = Group.Sku_Group_ID
```

Comment: No, is no reference table because is no needed - I would like just to see my "friendly name" instead of ID value at some specific situations but it is no needed for any other functionalities.